# QR Factorisation/decomposition using Householder matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have a QR factorisation question, here with the solution but i do not understand exactly what has been done. Could someone please explain?

> $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 3 \\2 & -6 & 3 \\-2 & 3 & -3\end{pmatrix}$

Solution says:

The first householder matrix $H(w_1)=I-2w_1{w^T}_1$ should map the first column vector $(1,2,-2)^T$ onto $||(1,2,-2)^T||_2e_1=3e_1$

**Why is it $3e_1$?**

It then says, thus we choose

$w_1=\frac{v_1}{||v||_1}$ with $ v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}-3{\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}$

and thus 
$w_1= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt 3}\begin{bmatrix}-2\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{ \sqrt 3}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

The rest of the solution i can see and understand what is going on but i just dont know how they got there. Could someone please explain where the 3 got here $||(1,2,-2)^T||_2e_1=3e_1$ in simple terms and why there is a square root of 3? Thanks

Comment: "$w_1=\frac{v_1}{||v||_{\color{red}1}}$". It should be $2$-norm. Do you know what $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is?

Comment: Square root/ absolute value? not sure about the 2 though to be honest tried to look it up online but its not an easy thing to look up! Can you please tell me what it is?

Comment: It helps to know the definitions.. See [p-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm).

Comment: well my lecturer has never mentioned a p-norm. I will look it up if you really cannot tell me :P

Comment: i have found it, it is exactly what i thought it was, still not getting the correct solution.

Comment: the solution says its a 1-norm which makes more sense as $\sqrt 1+2-2=3$ where as $\sqrt 1^2+2^2-2^2=5$

Comment: $||(1,2,-2)||_2=\sqrt{1^2+2^2+(-2)^2}=$ what? $||(1,2,-2)||_1=|1|+|2|+|-2|=$ what?